# Elasticsearch.Net API guide and examples/tutorial

Tags: elasticsearch-net

Is there a good place with tutorial on Elasticsearch.Net? How to build queries, etc.
I can't use NEST so trying go low level.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there a reason you can't use NEST?

Comment: Yes: I can't import it into SQL Server 2016. Idea was to create table function based on ES search.

Comment: Most of the documentation is geared towards NEST, but there is documentation on Elasticsearch.Net here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/elasticsearch-net.html. Most of the API endpoints on the low level client accept `PostData<object>` with implicit conversions to it from a few different types: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/post-data.html

Comment: Thank you.  I saw this already. Found solution without importing init SQL server